# Spring: How to create SINGLETON scoped bean dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, scope, singleton

In Spring 4 how do add to the context a new singleton-scoped bean?
I checked [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) class, but it only creates prototype-scoped beans not singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your `ApplicationContext`'s underlying `BeanFactory` and register the singleton.

```
ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("mySingleton", new Object());
//                                                    ^ whatever instance you
//                                                      want to add
```